# Interchange exponential of operators in quantum mechanics

Tags: operator-algebras, quantum-mechanics

What is the formula for interchanging products of exponential operators in quantum mechanics., i.e. I want to write $e^Ae^B = e^{B+...}e^A$

Answer (score 1):

The simplest formula you can get, I guess, is Trotter's product formula
$$
e^{A+B}=\lim_{n\to\infty}(e^{A/n}e^{B/n})^{n}.
$$